# ConnectionURI MSSQL Python

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection, simplejson, sqlobject

I'm coding a little something in Python. I need to get some data from a MicrosoftSQL database and convert it to a JSONObject. And i think i have some problems with the ConnectionForURI. I'm using simplejson and sqlobject libraries.

Im not sure exactly how that string is supposed to look like.

I'v tried this:

```
"mssql://COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS/DATABASENAME"
```

But getting the following error:

```
ImportError: Cannot find an MSSQL driver, tried adodb,pymssql
```

Is that becuase my connectionURI is wrong? I'v tried alot different with usernames and stuff, but i didn't need that when using pypyodbc.

Help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SQLObject sources don't install backend drivers, even as dependencies. You have to install one of the required drivers yourself: `pip install pymssql` (or adodb, or pyodbc).